# Why didn't Lisa tell the truth about Thorwald to the police?

Tags: plot-explanation, rear-window

Saw this 1959 Hitchcock's masterpiece [*Rear Window*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047396/) last night. One of the great classics! Enjoyed it!

I just didn't get one thing. Why didn't Lisa (Grace Kelly) tell the complete plot and truth about Thorwald when the police arrived at his home? Why did she get herself arrested and made the things more tense? Thorwald could have ran away from that place (but thank god it didn't happen)! :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason that Jeff doesn't immediately call the police with his suspicions: fear that if Thorwald realizes he has been made by an outside observer, he will dispose of all the evidence and escape without prosecution...

Lisa is buying more time by being taken under arrest, and the event was intended to appease Thorwald to some extent. He was already making mistakes (retaining his wife's wedding ring due to sentimentality), and Lisa was clinging onto the thought that their plan was not yet foiled. The arrest itself was actually a means of getting Lisa safely out of the apartment, and of getting the wedding ring (as evidence) into the hands of the police.

Comment: Police was there itself. How could Thorwald have dispose the evidence? Lisa should have handed over the ring to police straight away telling them the complete story. BUT yes  that event appeased Thorwald to some extent.

Comment: The police make a basic search of his house, and come up empty. They need something more substantial to become invasive, and as yet the evidence is largely circumstantial. They are playing for time.